# Dark Reader extension in firefox does not 'darken' local HTML file

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I have installed this extension called Dark Reader in firefox. It works flawlessly while browsing online. But, it does not darken the local html web pages which I have saved in my computer (which have white background) while loaded in firefox.

Here are the screenshots doing comparison between [loading local html file VS accessing the same web page online](https://sites.google.com/view/metalinmyveins3). I don't know how extensions work internally. So is there a way to darken the local html web pages too using this extension in firefox or is there any alternative extension which is able to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS